# A circuit or an i.c that will give a digital output high or low based on whether the input signal which is analog and is around 3.3V

Tags: analog

I need to check the performance of a DC/DC converter's output.The converter should give 3.3V   and does contain frequencies upto 8kHz in it(after using low pass filter).The bearable range for output voltage is 3.0V to 3.5V .Current from converter is very small around 40mamps. I need a circuit that will give a digital output high when the output voltage is not in this range.It should give a digital low when it is in  this range.

Comment: What if the output voltage is 1v? How would you expect it to give a digital output high? Is there a second power source?

Comment: What you're looking for is a window comparator (google that). There are special chips to monitor supply voltages. TPS3700 is one of them.

Comment: yes there is a second power source to give digital output high.

Answer (score 1):

Use two comparators like so:

[image: schematic]

I am not sure how your 8kHz signal comes into it, you haven't made it clear what you're talking about! Also, you have not said what voltage your second supply is at, or how well it is regulated etc. Lastly, you also have not said what voltages you want the output digital high/low to be, or how much current it must be able to supply. But the above should be a good starting point for you. If it is not sufficient, let me know why and we can work on it.

Comment: By saying 8kHz i mean the frequency of the noise signals that could be present in the signal. The second supply also from a converter and is regulated within 0.2V. and for the last question, for logic high any voltage above 1.2 V is fine .. Thanks for reply..waiting for your response

Answer (score 0):

You need to use what is known as a 'comparator' circuit. You can do this with an operational amplifier, or you can get dedicated logic chips which give a logic output.  The opamp implementation is very easy, just need a few resistors to set the threshold voltage. This is what I'd call a standard circuit, covered in just about every text book for opamps.

A better approach might be if you want a logic level output, compatible with other logic devices, is to use something like a CMOS voltage comparator, where you feed in an analogue voltage, set the threshold voltage on another pin, and the chip outputs a high or low logic level out.  Search the net for: "CMOS voltage comparator". I remember there were also chips in the TTL logic family 74xx for doing it too.  Take a look at: NCV2393, TS393

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the reply.. I would want to know whether this works for a range of 3-3.5v. How can we decide this using an opamp? can you help me with some calculations if needed?